# t-sql for json skip column names in a result

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I have the following t-sql query that returns json:

```
SELECT
    CF.Name
  , UCF.Value
FROM dbo.ClaimsCustomFields CF
LEFT JOIN dbo.UserCustomFields UCF
       ON UCF.FieldId = CF.Id
WHERE CF.CustomerId = 2653
FOR JSON PATH;
```

The output of this query is next:

```
    [  
   {  
      "Name":"zipCode",
      "Value":"zip zip zipC  zipCod"
   },
   {  
      "Name":"time111zone",
      "Value":"UTC +2"
   },
   {  
      "Name":"tttt",
      "Value":"Company organization tessss"
   }
]
```

But I want to get the result in the following format:

```
   [  
   {  
      "zipCode":"zip zip zipC  zipCod"
   },
   {  
      "time111zone":"UTC +2"
   },
   {  
      "tttt":"Company organization tessss"
   }
]
```

Is it possible to achive this with `FOR JSON` statement?

Comment: which sql server version?

Comment: @B3S sql-server 2017

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to generate a dynamic json, so you can try to use dynamic TSQL taking advantage of SQL Server 2017 new function `STRING_AGG` (more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)):

```
--this table contains your sample data
declare @tmp table([Name] varchar(50),[Value] varchar(50))
--this variable will contain the dynamic tsql command 
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

--this temp table will hold the dynamically generated json fragments
if object_id('#tmp') is null
    create table #tmp (js varchar(max))

--fill table with test data 
insert into @tmp values
    ('zipCode'     ,'zip zip zipC  zipCod'),
    ('time111zone' ,'UTC +2'),
    ('tttt'        ,'Company organization tessss')

--generate a TSQL command that inserts each single JSON fragment into a temp table
select @sql = string_agg('insert into #tmp(js) values((select ''' + [Value] +''' as ''' 
              + [Name]+'''  for json path , WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER))', ';') 
from @tmp

--execute the dynamic TSQL command that fills the temp table with JSON fragments
exec(@sql)

--concatenate all the JSON fragments adding square brackets
select '[' + string_agg(js,',') + ']' as result from #tmp
```

Results:

[image]

```
[{"zipCode":"zip zip zipC  zipCod"},{"time111zone":"UTC +2"},{"tttt":"Company organization tessss"}]
```